# When I tried to invoke thread.start(), it is not working first time

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I created this function and I want to use multithreading.

```
public String selectQuery(final String qry) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                statement = creatStatement();
                try {
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(qry);
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        fullName = resultSet.getString(1);
                    }
                    coloseConnection(resultSet);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    return fullName;

   // return null;
}
```

I invoked this function in button OnClick event, but when I called the first time, it doesn't display anything because the run method not executed after start thread but the second time it works.

I used debug mode to watch what is going. I searched the solution, but I didn't get the best solution.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running on another thread, `fullname` never actually gets set. So when you return fullName it's most likely still its initial value (probably null).

The second time you execute this, since the first thread has most likely finished its work you get a result.

This is a typical race condition.

The solution to this is either by using something like a `Consumer<String>` or, a really bad solution, which is locking the main thread until this is done.

The rule of thumb is you can't `return` from a multithreaded program and you have to use callbacks or locking. The preferred way is to use callbacks.